# Position a div to the right hand side of the screen

Tags: html, css

I currently have two divs on the left hand side of the screen, now I want to duplicate that on the right hand side. How would I do so?

html:

```
 <div id="contentOne">
<p style="font-size:18px; color:Gray; margin-left:50px;">Lorem Ipsum</p>
<hr style="border:1px solid Gray; width:150px;" />
<p style="text-align:center; color:White; z-index:999;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</p>
</div>

<div id="contentTwo">
<p style="font-size:18px; color:Gray; margin-left:50px;">Lorem Ipsum</p>
<hr style="border:1px solid Gray; width:150px;" />
<p style="text-align:center; color:White; z-index:999;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</p>
</div>

<div id="contentThree">
<p style="font-size:18px; color:Gray; margin-left:50px;">Lorem Ipsum</p>
<hr style="border:1px solid Gray; width:150px;" />
<p style="text-align:center; color:White; z-index:999;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</p>
</div>

<div id="contentFour">
<p style="font-size:18px; color:Gray; margin-left:50px;">Lorem Ipsum</p>
<hr style="border:1px solid Gray; width:150px;" />
<p style="text-align:center; color:White; z-index:999;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</p>
</div>
```

css:
http://codepad.org/kOsTA7FL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <div id="contentThree">
    <p style="font-size:18px; color:Gray; margin-left:50px;">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <hr style="border:1px solid Gray; width:150px;" />
    <p style="text-align:center; color:White; z-index:999;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
         Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
    </div>

    <div id="contentFour">
    <p style="font-size:18px; color:Gray; margin-left:50px;">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <hr style="border:1px solid Gray; width:150px;" />
    <p style="text-align:center; color:White; z-index:999;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
         Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="main">
    <div id="contentOne">
    <p style="font-size:18px; color:Gray; margin-left:50px;">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <hr style="border:1px solid Gray; width:150px;" />
    <p style="text-align:center; color:White; z-index:999;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
         Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
    </div>

    <div id="contentTwo">
    <p style="font-size:18px; color:Gray; margin-left:50px;">Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <hr style="border:1px solid Gray; width:150px;" />
    <p style="text-align:center; color:White; z-index:999;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
         Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main { width: 300px;   }
.pull-right { float: right; width: 300px; }
```

Answer (score 2):

use `float: right` as a CSS rule for the element you want aligned to the right of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:right;` to position at the right hand side of the screen.

to know more about float [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a container around all you Content# divs and specify a width for the container.

Then give each content a float:left and a width so that 2 fit nice next to eachother:

http://jsfiddle.net/PpyyR/

Alternatively. Use 2 containers, one for the right(float:right) and one for the left(float:left) and place your content in there:

```
.one{
    float:left;
}
.two{
     float:right;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PpyyR/1/